# How to display hex code value on screen using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, dom-events

I am creating a color picker web application and also want to show the hex code for the color on the screen. I used the value element in Javascript and the color is picking but it's not displaying the hex color code.

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=color]').forEach(function(picker){
var target = document.querySelector('label[for=" ' +picker.id+'"]'),
    colorArea = document.createElement(span);

    colorArea.innerHTML = picker.Value;
    target.appendChild(colorArea);

picker.addEventListener('change' , ()=>{
    colorArea.innerHTML = picker.Value;
    target.appendChild(colorArea);
});
```

});

It is the Javascript code I used in the web application.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide any html so i assumed one !
I upgraded tge code using some modern conventions like arrow functions  template strings etc...  Moreover there were some typos too ..

**HTML**

```
<label for="picker">
  <input type="color" name="" id="picker" value="" />
</label>
```

**Js**

```
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type=color]').forEach((picker) => {

    let target = document.querySelector(`label[for="${picker.id}"]`);
    colorArea = document.createElement('span');
    colorArea.innerHTML = picker.value; target.appendChild(colorArea);

    picker.addEventListener('change', ()=> {
      colorArea.innerHTML = picker.value; target.appendChild(colorArea);
    });

  });
```